# Remove a file with <Down> in the name?

Tags: linux, shell, files, command-line-interface

So, on a CentOS box, I accidentally executed `:w<Down>` in a `vim` editor, with "`<Down>`" being literally pressing the down arrow key on the keyboard (rendered onscreen as "`<Down>`"), and now I have a file named "`<Down>`" which I can't seem to get rid of; running "`rm <Down>`" (literally spelling out "less-than, D, o, w, n, greater-than") gives a syntax error.

How can I get rid of this file with the funky name?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use singlequotes to keep the control characters from being processed:

```
rm -f '<Down>'
```

Comment: We have all ran into this issue at some point when we first started out with linux. I for the longest time had trouble editing files with spaces in the name until I realized I could just put quotes around it.

Answer (score 9):

Use \ to escape special characters.  In this case, you would use

```
rm \<Down\>
```

Answer (score 5):

As an alternate solution:

```
$ ls -il .
total 0
1439039 -rw-r--r-- 1 medina foo 0 2010-07-15 16:48 ?????

# http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Deleting-Files
$ find . -inum 1439039 -delete
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I found to deal with all cases of escaping is using a scripting language:

```
$ cd /tmp/test/
$ ls
<Down>
$ python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:57:41) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.unlink('<Down>')
>>> quit()
$ ls
```

Answer (score 1):

type rm `<D`
and then press TAB
,
it will show suggestions, for the name of the desired file..

Comment: I deleted your duplicate answer - 'interesting' choice of icon by the way...